# Signal function not being called

Tags: c, signals, parent-child, kill, sigkill

I'm trying to send the child process a blank(SIGUSR1) signal from the parent. As far as I know, I have the signal set up properly. I feel like I am messing up on the Kill() function call. I expect some sort of printed output, but I get nothing. Not from inside the child nor from the signal function itself.

code:

```
void my_handler(int signum);

int main()
{
  pid_t pid;

  if((pid = fork()) == -1)
  {
    printf("Error on fork().\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(pid == 0)
  {
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler))
    {
     printf("+1"); 
    }
  }
  else if(pid > 0)
  {
    sleep(2);
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
  }

}

void my_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour: check the return values from system calls, such as `kill()`.  They tell you whether the system thinks the call worked or not.

Comment: Your child process is exiting as soon as it has installed the signal handler. It does not wait to receive the signal.

Comment: `printf()` is not async-signal-safe and should never be called from a signal handler.  Read the "**Async-signal-safe functions**" section:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You child exits before the signal is sent:

```
  if(pid == 0)
  {
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler))
    {
     printf("+1"); 
    }
  }
  else if(pid > 0)
  {
    sleep(2);
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
  }
```

The child might print `+1`, but then it exits.  Meanwhile, your parent waits two seconds to make sure the child is really dead, and then sends it a signal.  It isn't there!

**To fix**: Add some sort of code that makes the child hang around to receive the signal.  The simplest is probably `pause();`, though a `sleep()` for more than 2 seconds would work.

You should check your system calls.  For example:

```
if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "kill(%d) failed: %d %s\n", (int)pid, errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

You quickly get fed up with writing 4 lines of code so you end up with a function that reports a system error and exits (using C11 `_Noreturn`):

```
void _Noreturn err_syserr(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;  // Capture it before it changes
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errno != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}
```

Use:

```
if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) != 0)
    err_syserr("kill(%d) failed: ", (int)pid);
```

(Not everyone agrees with printing the error number; you pay your money and take your pick.)

See also [How to avoid using `printf` in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/)  It isn't a part of your problem, but you should be aware of the issues.

Answer (score 3):

The child process exits before the parent process has a chance to send a signal to it. Try adding `sleep(5)` in the child process after calling `signal`.

Comment: "*Try adding `sleep(5)` ...*"  or just call `pause()`.